# setState() does not trigger re-render

Tags: reactjs

Despite trying to avoid all the documented pitfalls which prevent React from re-rendering after state-change, I've still not been able to figure out my problem:

```
// Grid.js, render a grid of random-colored boxes

constructor(props){
        super(props); 
         this.initialcolors = this.initialcolors.bind(this); 
         this.updatecolors = this.updatecolors.bind(this);  
         this.state = {colors: this.initialcolors()}
    }

// ...

    updatecolors(index){
    let currentColors = [...this.state.colors];
    let currentColor = currentColors[index];
    let newColors = this.props.colors.filter(c => c !== currentColor)
    let newColor = newColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * newColors.length)];
    currentColors[index]=newColor; 
    this.setState(st => ({colors: currentColors}))
}

render(){
     return(<div>
           {this.state.colors.map( (color, index) => 
              <Box key={index} position={index} color={color} updatefunc={this.updatecolors} className="Box.css"/>
           )}
            </div>)
}

// Box.js, the colored box, onClick triggers state-change by calling updatefunc from parent

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {color: this.props.color}; 
    this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this); 
}

changeColor(evt){
    this.props.updatefunc(this.props.position); 
}

render(){
    return(
    <div style={{backgroundColor: this.state.color, 
                 height: 100, 
                 width: 100, 
                 padding: 0.5}} 
         onClick={this.changeColor}> </div>
    )
}
```

}

The update-function is called from each box-component and triggers assignment of a new color on the box grid.

Trying to avoid the usual mistakes:

- The color-array is only modified after being copied from the state via spread operator
- The new array is passed via setState()
- In addition, I took care of the instance binding for the functions in both components

However, despite onClick successfully triggering the state change, there is no re-render taking place. What is the additional aspect that I am missing here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Its a bad to directly assign props to state in the component.

Comment: Yes, but is this also true for assigning just a single part of the props-structure:  this.state = {color: this.props.color};  ?

Answer (score 1):

Box.js is using `this.state.color` as the backgroundColor, which never changes because the constructor is only called once per box. You probably want to use `this.props.color` which has the changed color from Grid.

```
class Box extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this); 
  }

  changeColor (evt) {
    this.props.updatefunc(this.props.position); 
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: this.props.color, 
          height: 100, 
          width: 100, 
          padding: 0.5
        }} 
        onClick={this.changeColor}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense: onClick triggers the parent state change -> re-render via map function with updated props -> new color goes into props of each child component, constructor remains untouched.